# Retrieve img src from itunes page

Tags: php, domdocument

In the url

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wechat/id414478124?mt=8

there's the image which is in the html in this following manner

```
<div class="artwork">
<img class="artwork" width="175" height="175" src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/64/d2/e1/64d2e14d-9339-32f0-9382-77c158a90941/icon175x175.png" src-swap="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/64/d2/e1/64d2e14d-9339-32f0-9382-77c158a90941/icon175x175.png" src-load-auto-after-dom-load="" src-swap-high-dpi="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple1/v4/64/d2/e1/64d2e14d-9339-32f0-9382-77c158a90941/icon350x350.png" alt="WeChat">
<span class="mask"></span>
</div>
```

Now as you can see, both the  and the  have the same class name.

I use this following piece of code to extract the src from the image

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wechat/id414478124?mt=8');
libxml_clear_errors();
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$image_src = $xp->query("//img[@class='artwork']");
echo $image_src->item(0)->getAttribute('src'). "<br/>";
```

But it returns me only

https://s.mzstatic.com/htmlResources/1583/frameworks/images/p.png

which when seen through the browser address bar, gives only black page

Comment: That's becasue they are generating image classes using 'javascript'. view the actual page source. not the generated page. you might wanna look into `src-swap` or similar attributes.

Comment: You might also want to use [the JSON description of the object](https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=414478124).

Answer (score 0):

It is because the static HTML page has that address as a source. Either run through a JavaScript evaluator OR see the other attributes, like `src-swap`

If you want to get the JavaScript rendered page, there is e.g. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) that you can probably use, but in this case since the answer is already there, but with a different attribute, it's faster not to use anything to evaluate the JS.